# OpenCL: how to optimise a reduction kernel (summation of columns), currently the CPU is faster

Tags: macos, optimization, opencl

I have started to use OpenCL for the first time and I'm trying to optimise a reduction kernel. The kernel take a square grid of floating point numbers (the data represents the luminance value of a greyscale image) of size width-by-length pixels. The kernel sums along every column and returns the total for each column to an output array.

```
/* 
input  -- "2D" array of floats with width * height number of elements
output -- 1D array containing summation of column values with width number of elements
width  -- number of elements horizontally
height -- number of elements vertically

Both width and height must be a multiple of 64.
*/
kernel void sum_columns(global float* input, global float* output,  int width, int height)
{        
    size_t j = get_global_id(0);
    float sum = 0.0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<height; i++) {
        sum += input[i + width*j];
    }
    output[j] = sum;
}
```

OpenCL should make a perform every column summation in concurrently because I set the global dimensions to be the number of columns in the data. I have used Instruments.app on MacOS and timed how long 1000 iterations of the kernel takes when executing on the CPU and the GPU. This can be done by specifying the device to be either `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU` or `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU`.

The performance is **not** good! In fact the CPU is consistently faster than the GPU, which strikes me as very odd. Is there something wrong with the kernel? How can the CPU be faster when at most it can only execute about 8 threads concurrently?

The code for this project is here (an Xcode project), https://github.com/danieljfarrell/Xcode-4-OpenCL-Example.

Here are the timing results as I increase the size of the data,

[image: Execution time as a function of image size.]

**Update**

The timing for the CPU and GPU are simply implied from looking at the time taken to run the kernel using Instruments.app,
[image: Screenshot showing Instruments.app using interface with the execution time for the kernel highlighted.]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which GPU was used to benchmark?

Comment: You are right, CPU is faster than GPU in your code. GT650M and Core i7-3615QM. An aspect I will look at is that the time isn't used to do the calculation, but for something else. I am not really that familiar with OpenCL, but I will probably dig that way.

Comment: I made an update, but basically I look at the execution time of the kernel using Instruments (see the screenshot above).

Comment: I see. Anyway, I believe there are some jobs that won't run much faster on GPUs, or sometimes even slower.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, What do you get when you asked opencl for the suggested block size. i.e 'wgs' in your code. And how many computing units doesn your gpu have?

Comment: GT650M: Unified Shaders (Vertex shader/Geometry shader/Pixel shader) : Texture mapping unit : Render Output unit = 384:32:16

Comment: OpenCL always selects 128 for the CPU and 1024 for the GPU. I have a NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE is 1024 and CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS is 2 (http://clbenchmark.com/device-environment.jsp?config=12783180)

Comment: Okay, I find a possible reason why you get this result. The **raw** performance of GT 650M is higher than 3615QM on my machine. However, with a OpenCL benchmarking application like LuxMark, GT 650M performs terribly! CPU-only benchmarking got an 298, while GPU got only 81. For whatever reason, GT 650M found only two compute units on OS X. And that can really leads to a terrible slow down.

Comment: I thought it was the workgroup size that determines the concurrent throughput? I'm not too sure how to interpret the "compute unit" concept.

Comment: If opencl selects 4 threads per group and the GPU has (let's say) 2 compute units (multi-processors) with 16 cores each while the CPU has 4 cores (which opencl considers as 4 compute units). Now when runnin on GPU you are potentialy wasting 12 of the cores since your work group needs only 4 of the cores at once. If the CPU has a better processor speed then it will finish faster than the GPU. Because the GPU is not used optimally.

Comment: That makes sense, but why would it only select 4 threads? Is there a way to ask how many threads it is using?

Comment: I would like to add that the CPU can be used more efficiently still.  You can use the SIMD instructions on the cores as wells as threading to get even better results on the CPU
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430069/reduction-with-openmp-with-sse-avx

Answer (score 4):

One easy improvement to try is to make the input constant memory instead of global. You need to set it up with CL_MEM_READ_ONLY when you create the buffer. The profiler I use seems to like your kernel as it is when I change only that parameter to __constant.

Another option is to transpose the input matrix, so you're not trying to read columns of memory. I made a kernel that uses an entire work group to sum a row of data and yield a single entry in output. The __constant parameter also helps this kernel out a lot, making it the only run to be ALU-bound instead of global-fetch-bound out of the four trials I ran.

I didn't loop though the height parameter, but you can either set that up or create enough work groups for your output data (1 per element).

```
kernel void sum_rows(__constant  float* input, global float* output,  int width, int height)
{        
    int gid = get_local_id(0);
    int gsize = get_local_size(0);
    local float sum[64]; //assumes work group size of 64
    sum[gid] = 0;
    int i;
    int rowStart = width * get_group_id(0);
    for(i=gid; i<width; i+=gsize) {
        sum[gid] += input[rowStart + i];
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    if(gid == 0){
        for(i = 0;i<64;i++){
            sum[0] += sum[i];
        }
        output[get_group_id(0)] = sum[0];
    }
}
```

Beyond that, I suggest looking at host-level optimizations. With a large enough data set, there should be no problem for a gpu to outperform a cpu in a reduction kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there are tradeoffs when using OPenCL, which may actually result in slower performances when using OpenCL for certain tasks.

Maybe you could try to increase the work actually performed on the GPU so it oversteps the cost of setting up the context.

Note that not every job may benefit from OpenCL, and most of the time you will have to do some testing in order to decide whether or not your application may benefit from it.

*See: [What kind of work benifits from OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869929/what-kind-of-work-benifits-from-opencl)*

- **The overhead of setting up a context and transferring data**

> *Due to the overhead of setting up a context and transferring data over a PCI bus, you must be processing a fairly large data set before
>   you see any benefits from using OpenCL.* The exact point at which you
>   start to see benefits depends on the OpenCL implementation and the
>   hardware being used, so you will have to experiment to see how fast
>   you can get your algorithm to execute. In general, a high ratio of
>   computation to data access and lots of mathematical computations are
>   good for OpenCL programs.

Source: [OpenCL Programming guide for MAC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/IdentifyingParallelizableRoutines/IdentifyingParallelizableRoutines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH9-SW1)

- **Small Jobs / too fractionned jobs perform better on the CPU**

For instance, if the job you execute with OpenCL is to small, or to fractionated, you will loose more time setting up everything, than you gain by performing the actual job using OpenCL.

> The more segmentation code I add, the slower the OpenCL code becomes.
>   
> […]
>   *3 things will kill you.*  
> The latency of calling OpenCL. Meaning,
>   it takes more time to call an OpenCL function than it does a "real
>   Java/C# function". 
> Second, it takes a fair amount out of time, for the
>   GPU to access main computer memory and copy stuff to it.
>   [...]

Source: [Current issues in OpenCL (2010)](http://www.heatonresearch.com/node/1750)

- **There is also this page in which the benchmarker states:**

> Cleary you see that the GPU outperforms CPU at higher values of size
>   as the program is able to use multiple threads provided by the GPU. At
>   lower values of size there is an appreciable access time associated
>   with GPU, so CPU performs faster.

Source: [CPU vs GPU performance comparision with OpenCL](http://advencode.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/performance-comparision-of-using-opencl-with-my-gpu/) (Oct. 2011)

Comment: I am aware of these issues, it's important to saturate the GPU. But I would expect this case to actually be better suited to GPU computation as it's essentially image data! That's why I'm I was wondering how to best optimise the kernel.

Comment: Well, as stated in this answer: most of your optimization should focuss on:  `In general, a high ratio of computation to data access and lots of mathematical computations are good for OpenCL programs. You will have to experiment to see how fast you can get your algorithm to execute.` *As a side note: On the Apple Mailing lists, they have `perfoptimization-dev` list. I know for a fact that several experts in OpenCL frequently drop in to answer questions*.

Comment: @ShaneHsu Actually, I have spent a lot of time messing with OpenCL to discover that… not any set of parallelizable tasks can benefit from it.

Comment: Is the computation you perform useful to you? I mean, if you are to optimize, do it on the real thing, not on a simple example (because some too simple tasks may never perform better on a GPU). The issue of openCL samples is that the computation is pretty straightforward and the costs related to actually using openCL are higher.

Comment: This is really great background, thank you! But the answer I was looking for was more on how to begin the optimisation process. I don't want to give up too early.

Comment: Yes, it would be really useful, and the example I have set up is more or less exactly the problem I want to solve, both in terms of image size and content (the bits per pixel).

Comment: To begin, add some heavier computation in your loop, just to see how your curve evolve and to check that everything is properly setup. The time it takes to execute the job should be way larger than the time for the OpenCL setup and data retrieval. *Hint: perfoptimization-dev ;)*

Comment: @boyfarrell In my answer, I added a link towards http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869929/what-kind-of-work-benifits-from-opencl

Answer (score 3):

You need to break your problem down into multiple kernel runs. Having large loops (in this case "height" will likely be large) is bad in OpenCL and also you need to unroll any loops. You can do this automatically using "#pragma unroll X" where "X" is the number of times the loop will run.

Now your problem gets marginally more difficult because you need to break it up into multiple kernel runs. Here are the steps:

1. Determine the max number that can be unrolled and then have each thread only operate on that many elements.
2. Use the loop unrolling discussed
3. This will generate partial sums for each column.
4. run the kernel again and again until you only have a small amount of sums (Determine this number by trial and error)
5. sum the final partial sums on the CPU.
   Note: Do not copy the partial sums back to the CPU until the final CPU-sumation step.

There are other strategies but this will be the first step to actually have the GPU win in this computation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I agree with **mfa** it would be better if you have your data transposed. This way you will read data from global memory sequentially (search for bank conflicts). But this is only one thing.

Other thing is to change your algoritm. Current drawbacks of your approach 1) you have small number of work items - equal to height of your image. 2) long cycle.

I'd suggest you to rewrite your algo to actually make it parallel next way:
E.g. you have to sum 512 items. Then you run workgroup that has 256 work items.
each work item adds up 2 values. E.g. 1st will add v[1]=v[0]+v[1], 2nd v[3] = v[2]+v[3] and so on. So, after first operation you'll have pair sums in odd indices. Next cycle you make similar procedure, but only 128 work items do the job, because you already have only 256 elements to process. The only difference that now 1st work item will do v[3] = v[1]+v[3], 2nd v[7] = v[5] + v[7] and so on.
This way you have 1) O(logN) complexity instead of O(N) 2) you spawn more items which do less work. -> benefit from parallelization.

Of course you will need to call barrier(...) instruction after every write to sync calculations between work items in work group.

To speed up even more, first each work group copies its values from global to local memory and performs calculations using local memory.

One question, that you might want to ask: "**What if i need to sum too many values (say 100000) and i cant create work group with such big number of work items**". In this case you do partial sums and then run your kernel second time to sum those partial sums. Because you can't synchronize between work groups while executing kernel.

To be more clear here is the code. It sums 2 x blockSize values. Hope I did not make any mistakes (did not actually compile this one)

```
// run Work group with local size = (BLK_SIZ, 1), global size = ( width, height )
__kernel void calc_sum(__global float* d_in, __global float* d_sums, const int rowLen)
{

    int our_row = get_global_id(1);
    int lx = get_local_id(0);
    int gr = get_group_id(0);

    __local float our_mem[(2*BLK_SIZ)];

    // copy glob -> loc mem
    our_mem[2*lx + 0] = d_in[gr*2*BLK_SIZ + 2*lx + 0];
    if(gr*2*BLK_SIZ + 2*lx + 0 >= rowLen)
        our_mem[2*lx + 0] = 0;

    our_mem[2*lx + 1] = d_in[gr*2*BLK_SIZ + 2*lx + 1];
    if(gr*2*BLK_SIZ + 2*lx + 1 >= rowLen)
        our_mem[2*lx + 1] = 0;

    // do the calculations

    int width = 2;
    int num_el = 2*BLK_SIZ / width;
    int wby2 = width>>1;
    for(int i = 0;i<7;++i) 
    {
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        if(lx < num_el)
        {
            int idx = width*(lx + 1) - 1;
            our_mem[idx] = min(our_mem[idx], our_mem[idx-wby2]);
        }
        width<<=1;
        wby2 = width>>1;
        num_el>>=1;
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    // store res
    if(lx == 0) // choose some element from work group to actualy write the sum
    {
        d_sums[our_row] = our_mem[2*lx-1]; // sum is in last element
    }
}
```

Also search in the internet for blelloch / hillis steele parallel prefix sum algoritms.
nVidia also has nice example with good documentation for parallel prefix sum algorithm. It does more than you need, but has same approach that I've described.

Hope this helps.